# Executing stored procedure from ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

i need help in passing prefix to a system procedure..

```
exec [your database name]..sp_tables
```

Here in above code the [your database name] should be a textbox value
here is my code..

```
string DatabaseName = txtbox.Text;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("exec ['"+DatabaseName+"']..sp_tables", conn))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "TABLE_NAME";
            DropDownList2.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
        }
```

I am getting error

```
 Database '.net'' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

when I execute

```
 exec [.net]..sp_tables
```

I get the result correctly
Any suggestion ??
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're prepending and appending a single quote thus the error. DBnames dont need the quotes.

Try:

`new SqlDataAdapter("exec ["+DatabaseName+"]..sp_tables", conn))`

Answer (score 0):

```
exec [your database name]..sp_tables

Here in above code the [your database name] should be a textbox value here is my code..

string DatabaseName = txtbox.Text;
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("exec ["+DatabaseName+"]..sp_tables", conn))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "TABLE_NAME";
            DropDownList2.DataSource = ds;
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
```